# What does the "id" mean in leakcanary

Tags: android, leakcanary

I used [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect memory leak
and found this in the log:

```
D  |   [38] = android.graphics.Bitmap [id=0x12d81740]
```

But I am not sure what the `id=0x12d81740` mean？ is it the hash id get by
`System.identityHashCode(mBitmap)`?, I have searched the code, but did not find something relative.

Answer (score 0):

Same id means same instance.

I think it looks like the return value of `java.lang.Object#hashCode`